# Ajax don't go in succes function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps

My google maps application still doesn't work. I'm getting closer and closer to the end. At this moment my success function of my ajax function does not run.
I think there is something wrong with the data parsing,... I tried many things but nothing works.. Here is my controller and html/ajax/javascript code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple Map</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            #map {
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAurjHVf3PDdmkha_9kHBC7b-Go0CXbWPI&v=3.2&sensor=false"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var map;https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js
            var data;
            initMap();
            function initMap() {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
                    zoom: 8
                });


                httpCall();
            }

            function httpCall($http) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '<?php echo site_url('User/marks') ?>',
                    data: data,
                    dataType: "json",
                    complete: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                        for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; ++i) {
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: {
                                    lat: parseFloat(data[i].lat),
                                    lng: parseFloat(data[i].lng)
                                },
                                map: map
                            });
                        }
                    }
                })
            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

controller :

```
function marks() {
    $data = json_encode($this->user_model->get_marks());
    return $data;
}
```

Network in firefox :

[image: http://i65.tinypic.com/2n1crqe.png]

Comment: Can you give us an example of the JSON? Also you have an url after your `map` variable. `var map;https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js`

Comment: can you see ajax call in your browser window in network tab?

Comment: My function now is going into the success function but I think the data object is still empty. When i alert it, it gives a 'Object' but I can't do more with it..

Comment: When I do "alert(JSON.stringify(data));" it gives "{"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}" . Not the respond I want..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the documentation for your `complete` callback. There are no arguments for the result:

> complete Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus )

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

You should use the `success` callback.

> success Type: Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR
>   )

---

Edit: Instad of doing `return data`, do `echo data`.

Comment: My function now is going into the success function but I think the data object is still empty. When i alert it, it gives a 'Object' but I can't do more with it..

Comment: When I do "alert(JSON.stringify(data));" it gives "{"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}" . Not the respond I want..

Comment: instead of doing "return data" do "echo data"

Comment: nice, that's an improvement. Thank you!

Comment: @user5488652 if that answers your question, make sure to mark this answer as right. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'mypage.html',
  success: function(){
    alert('success');
  },
  error: function(){
    alert('failure');
  }
});
```

**Above is an example of an ajax request with a success function, you don't seem to have one. Also try calling the URL by hard coding it first to make sure it's even getting it correctly.  **

Comment: My function now is going into the success function but I think the data object is still empty. When i alert it, it gives a 'Object' but I can't do more with it..

Comment: When I do "alert(JSON.stringify(data));" it gives "{"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}" . Not the respond I want..

Comment: Try alerting data[0] to find the first element in the JSON.
Also try doing an alert(data[0].name) or whatever you have in your JSON, it's hard to give an answer without seeing the JSON.
You don't need JSON Stringify function you have your JSON data back you can now access it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code missing below code

**"contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",**

in ajax call.

please add contenttype into $.ajax and try to call service

Answer (score 0):

You didn't have Content Type and Success in your ajax request. Here is updated code of yours

```
            function httpCall($http) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '<?php echo site_url('User/marks') ?>',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: data,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; ++i) {
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: {
                                lat: parseFloat(data[i].lat),
                                lng: parseFloat(data[i].lng)
                            },
                            map: map
                        });
                    }
                }
            })
        }
```

Once this request done successfully, You will get data in alert.